# Laravel WhereHas all data control

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have a customers table. These customers have a `customer_request` table, and a customer can have more than one claim record. And there's a table of floors. The multiples table has a `customer_request_floors` table that is associated with the customer claims table. They are all related to each other. I want to filter customers who have demand according to the selected multiples when filtering customers.

In the search I use below, I want to filter it according to the latest requests of customers. When I filter as follows, it brings me linked records of that user's other requests. For example, let the customer have 2 requests. Let these be two different floor records. I'd like to search between multiples of the last request. When I filter as follows, it returns the registered `floor_id` in 2 requests. I'm shooting your last request using a model. Can you help with filtering?

What I really want to look for is to filter the records with `floor_id` that I send in the pivot Table, which depends on the final demand from the customers.

`Customer` model:

```
public function lastRequest()
{
    return $this->hasOne(CustomerRequest::class)->latest();
}
```

Search model:

```
$this->customers = $this->customers->whereHas('lastRequest', function ($customer_request){
    $customer_request->whereHas('floors', function($floors) {
       $floors->whereIn('floor_id', $this->params['floor_ids']);
    });
});
```

`CustomerRequest` model:

```
public function floors()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Floor::class, 'customer_request_floors');
}
```

`customer_request_floors` pivot table

```
protected $fillable = [
   'customer_request_id', 'floor_id'
];
```

Comment: Sorry, it isn't clear what you're asking for. Please can give a brief explanation to what isn't working with your example.

Comment: Hi, sorry, please. I updated the article. Thanks for your concern